# Вывод списка в Python в формате 2**(N-1)

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу!
Имеем список . Как вывести его элементы в таком виде в столбик:
шаг1
n
шаг2
n,n
шаг3
n,n,n,n
шаг4
n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n
........................
т.е. в каждой строке количество элементов равно 2 **(N-1), где N номер строки вывода.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

итерируешься по циклу и умножаешь строки на формулу свою. строки прекрасно умножаются.

Comment: Прочитайте вопрос внимательно пожалуйста

Comment: @Az1kha4 прочитайте правила сайта внимательно пожалуйста

Comment: @Az1kha4 Учебное задание за вас делать не будут, только могут подсказать направление.

Comment: и кто подсказал? при чем здесь умножение строк?

Comment: ты серьезно? что "значит" вывести? куда вывести? покурить вывести? когда меня просят вывести что-то куда-то то я понимаю что мне это что-то нужно в функцию print отправить. значит мы точно о строках.